# Calculating PDF and CDF

Tags: probability, density-function

[image]

I solved this question and here are my answers, can you confirm whether they are correct?

(a) k = -2
(b) E(x)= 2ln(2)
(c) Var(x) = 0.0782
(d) CDf = 2 - 2/x
(e) P(X<=0.05) = 0
(f) pdf = e^(-x/2)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to (c) is $2 - (\ln4)^2$, you shouldn't just write the approximation.

Your answer to (d) is only correct for $1 \le x \le 2$, you also need to write down the remaining part.

Your density in part (f) is only correct for $0 \le x \le \ln 4$.

The rest is correct.